# jQuery device orientation range converting to percentage between 0 and 100

Tags: jquery, css, gyroscope, device-orientation

I'm trying to control an HTML element by using the gyroscope in my smartphone. I managed to extract the gyroscope's values (Alpha, Beta and Gamma) but can't manage to translate it in such a way it's able to manipulate objects the way I'd like to.

**The starting position of the device is in landscape mode, right in front of the user; just like a flatscreen television. The device will be inserted in a Google Cardboard viewer.**

The attached image explains what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

1. An objects "Left" percentage in CSS.
2. Device orientation while rotating head from left to right

I can't seem to find a way to "convert" the range of the rotaion movement to a percentage value between 0 and 100%.

For example:

- If I look slightly left, the Alpha value is around 22/23 and the left percentage should be around 25.
- If I look slightly right, the Alpha value is around 338/337 and the left percentage should be around 75.

Could you guys help me out?

Best regards,

Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got this a bit wrong, check for more details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation

> - The **DeviceOrientationEvent.alpha** value represents the motion of the device around the z axis, represented in degrees with values
>     ranging from 0 to 360.
> - The **DeviceOrientationEvent.beta** value represents the motion of the device around the x axis, represented in degrees with values
>     ranging from -180 to 180. This represents a front to back motion of
>     the device.
> - The **DeviceOrientationEvent.gamma** value represents the motion of the device around the y axis, represented in degrees with values
>     ranging from -90 to 90. This represents a left to right motion of the
>     device.

est-west and north-south position, notice z is not represented in x y axis

> - **x - beta:** Represents the axis from West to East
> - **y - gamma:** Represents the axis from South to North
> - **z - alpha:** Represents the axis perpendicular to the ground

Going forward with CSS props:

> - **x - beta:** Represents top property
> - **y - gamma:** Represents left property
> - **z - alpha:** not necessary usable in a 2d css but you can use it for zoom or angle to a 2d shape, div or image.

For left property, you should use gamma device orientation, here is a nice example (masonry level gama) where left css prop in percent is used to position the level point.

try form here on mobile: https://jsfiddle.net/f7tdrb87/

percentage computation:

```
function precentageIn180(value)
{
    var percent =  ((value * 100) / 180).toFixed(0);
  return percent;
}
```

and the interval [-90, 90] transposed into [0, 180] where 0 == 0% and 180 == 100%, so then `event.gamma + 90` is used all the time;

```js
var point   = document.querySelector('.point');
var masonryLevel = document.querySelector('.masonry-level-gama');
var log = document.querySelector('.log');

var maxY = masonryLevel.clientWidth - point.clientWidth;

function precentageIn180(value)
{
 var percent =  ((value * 100) / 180).toFixed(0);
  return percent;
}

function handleOrientation(event) {
  var y = event.gamma; // In degree in the range [-90,90]
  log.innerHTML = "gamma: " + y + "\n";
  //value on gama is [-90, 90] => but we want to have between [0, 180], to be possiblle to compute 100% of 180
  y += 90;
  var percent = precentageIn180(y);
  log.innerHTML += "gamma percent: " + percent + "\n";
  point.style.left = (percent + "%");
}



window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', handleOrientation);
```

```css
.masonry-level-gama {
  position: relative;
  width : 190px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.point {
  position: absolute;
  top   : 10px;
  left  : 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  width : 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="masonry-level-gama">
  <div class="point"></div>
</div>
<pre class="log"></pre>
```

Comment: I get where you're going! However I forgot to describe the starting orientation of the device which is in landscape mode with the screen in front of the user; like looking at a TV.

It's important for the user not to turn 360º in order for the object to span the entire 100% length of the viewport. Instead I'd like a range within the 360º as illustrated in the image above.

In an angle of 90º (45º left, 45º right) the element should go from 0% to 100%.
I hope I'm explaining well enough.

Comment: Well then you should use beta orientation, and the [-180 to 180] will bee  [0, 360] and the percent, so var x = event.gamma + 180, percent = ((x * 100) / 360)

Comment: I can't seem to get your suggestion working due to my lack of knowledge on this matter. Definitely a step in the right direction though. Also, if a specific range within that 360º (90º preferably) transposes the scale from 0% to 100% that'd be amazing.

Comment: I will give it a shot, to do a test (so the device is in landscape), the start position will be the center, 50% in percents

Comment: Thanks heaps! It's almost exactly what I'm trying to achieve. I still have to do some minor tweaks but thanks to the code you provided it'll be much easier.